# Nomogram plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reproduce Naive Bayes nomogram as given in [Nomograms for Visualization of Naive Bayesian Classifier by Mozina](http://iccle.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/share/pdf/mozina04.pdf). It is a great visualization for looking at Bayes probabilities. I have been searching and trying various things, but no luck. (I am unable to put all the points on one row for a column.) I've computed probabilities and put them in a data frame called `df`

```
structure(list(.id = c("outlook", "outlook", "outlook", "windy", 
"windy"), variablevalue = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L), .Label = c("sunny", 
"overcast", "rainy", "'All'", "FALSE", "TRUE"), class = "factor"), 
prob = c(0.222222222222222, 0.444444444444444, 0.333333333333333, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333)), .Names = c(".id", 
"variablevalue", "prob"), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 11L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's how the chart would like (this chart is all cut and paste):
[image: nomogram]

Comment: I should also say that this type of a chart is implemented in [orange](http://orange.biolab.si/), which is Python based. And `R` also has a `nomogram`, but that is for regression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?

```
ggplot(df, aes(prob,.id,label=variablevalue)) + 
  geom_text() + 
  xlim(c(0,1))
```

[image]

Comment: this is awesome! for some reason I couldn't wrap my head around this. thank you very much. How did you get the labels not to overlap?

Comment: Setting the limits of the plot seemed to help. You could also use geom_text(position="jitter") if you have a number of words to show.